# Pass params between ng-click and a service Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a "search" where the user input a value and i want to send this value in the service because i want that another controller can have access. But for the moment i can't do it, if someone can help me it would be very usfull i using Angular js.

And the js

```js
var app = angular.module('MainApp', [])

app.factory('Search', function($rootScope, $http){
var search = '';
 function setSearch(bus){
  search = bus;
 }
 function getSearch(){
  return search;
 }
 return{
  setSearch : setSearch,
  getSearch: getSearch

 };
 //return myFactory;
 /*
 $scope.Search = function() {
  return {
   getDoctor: function () {
    return $http.get('api/doctor' + $scope.search.searchText).then(function (response) {
     orders = response.data;
     $rootScope.$broadcast('handleSharedOrders', orders);
     return orders;
    })
   }
  };
 }*/
});

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, Search) {


 $scope.loadList = function() {
  location.href = "doctors";
 };

$scope.search.searchText = Search.getSearch();
 $scope.Search = function(bus) {
  console.log(bus);
  Search.setSearch(bus);


 }


 $scope.doctors = {};
 $http.get('/api/doctor').success(function (data) {
  $scope.doctors = data;
 })
  .error(function (data) {
   console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });


 /*
 $http.get('/api/doctor/' + specialty).success(function (data) {
  $scope.doctorsSpecialty = data;
 })
  .error(function (data) {
   console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
*/


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MainApp">
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Cargamos app -->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../Controllers/core.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div align="center">
 <img src="../img/logo.jpg" >
</div>





<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <div class="login-panel panel panel-default"  >
    <div class="panel-heading" >
     <h3 class="panel-title">Search Doctors</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" >
     <form role="form"   >
      <fieldset>
       <div class="form-group" name="myForm"  >
        <input ng-model="search.searchText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." align="center">
       </div>
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" align="center" ng-click="Search(searchText)">
        <b align="center">Search</b>
       </button>
       <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>

   </div>
   <div class="panel-heading" STYLE="background-color: #a7b5ce">
    <h3 class="panel-title">List of Doctors</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body" >
    <form role="form">
     <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group" name="myForm"  >
       <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" align="center" href=doctors ng-click="loadList()">
        <b>List of Doctors</b>
       </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
     </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Here you have defined `search.searchText`:

```
<input ng-model="search.searchText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." align="center">
```

And here you are trying to pass just `searchText` (which is undefined):

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" align="center" ng-click="Search(searchText)">
    <b align="center">Search</b>
</button>
```

You need to either change your `ng-model` on your `<input>` to be 'search' or change the `ng-click` on your `<button>` to 'Search(search.searchText)'. If you choose to do the latter you may also want to explicitly create the `search` object in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were doing it well, but your code has a few errors. First, you are not declaring the object search in your scope but you are assigning the property searchText to it. So you should do something like that:

```
$scope.search = {
        searchText: ''
    };
```

Then, in the view when you click search you are passing searchText but it should be search.searchText.

Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/jruizx/54xcmgqp/